# Why authority is so complex?

Tags: jhipster

I cannot understand why [Authority](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/038a65052931c41750828e6e2b831724696e254b/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/domain/_Authority.java) is so complex in JHipster? What's the reason for creating another entity with only one field `name`? Furthermore it has a *csv* file that uploads a template to the database with Liquibase.
There was an idea for me to create an enum (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5539391/4725496)):

```
@Entity
@Table
public enum Authority {

    USER, ADMIN;

    @Id
    private String title = "ROLE_" + name();

}
```

Then I decided that this is not necessary too. It can be an enum without annotations and just a `Set` (or even an `EnumSet`):

```
private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
```

Did I miss something? Maybe it's useful for JPA?
I wanted to create an issue on GitHub but I think it's a better place.

Answer (score 1):

GrantedAuthority is defined by Spring Security and default implementation SimpleGrantedAuthority has only a role name but it can be extended to have more attributes so I guess that JHipster's entity enables this possibility.

Comment: But how does the entity help to work with GrantedAuthority? I can still do `new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Authority.ADMIN.toString())`. I just think that `authorityRepository.findOne("ROLE_USER")` is unnecessary in the registration and other parts of the app and we can just use `Collections.singleton(Authority.USER)`.

Comment: It seems to me that you only imagine a static list of roles. In the case of a gateway, you can easily create new roles from user management that are not interpreted by the gateway code itself (so no constant, no enum) and get interpreted from JWT claims in a proxified microservice.

Comment: I'm sure there are other reasons but that's the one I'm using now on a project :)